# Sankey diagram get cutoff

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-google-charts

The chart is cutoff for some parts even set the chart height higher. The container height is set as 100% so that it will resize follow the chart height. Even changed the container height > chart height, still the chart get cutoff.

```
<Chart
      chartType="Sankey"
      data={hardcodedData}
      height="1000px"
      options={options}
      columns={columns}
      loader={<RadialProgressBar height="600px" />}
      chartEvents={chartEvents as any}
    />
```

**Result**

[image]

Expected the chart to fit as height set where all the data is visible easily.